How to use WebView2 AddBrowserExtensionAsync in UWP?
I've try webView.CoreWebView2.Profile.AddBrowserExtensionAsync(extensionPath), got exception "The request is not supported."
I know i have to set AreBrowserExtensionsEnabled as True, found the property in CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions, but CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync can no longer pass CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions parameters like WPF.
So what should I do? Am I missing something?

Conclusion from this question, please use CoreWebView2Environment.CreateWithOptionsAsync(CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions) to enable the AreBrowserExtensionsEnabled and add Environment in EnsureCoreWebView2Async(CoreWebView2Environment).
